# Map headers with values

Tags: json, jq

I have a "kind of JSON" (I have no idea if this is a standard format) which I would like to parse with jq. I have tried a ton of variations but I can't get it to work with jq.

The "JSON" looks like this:

```
{
   "headers" : [
      "key1",
      "key2",
      "key3",
   ],
   "rows" : [
      [
         "value1",
         "value2",
         "value3"
      ],
      [
         "value1",
         "value2",
         "value3"
      ],
      [
         "value1",
         "value2",
         "value3"
      ]
   ],
   "total_rows" : "3"
}
```

I would like to use the headers section as keys for each row. So the output should look like this:

```
  [
     "key1" : "value1",
     "key2" : "value2",
     "key3" : "value3"
  ],
  [
     "key1" : "value1",
     "key2" : "value2",
     "key3" : "value3"
  ],
  [
     "key1" : "value1",
     "key2" : "value2",
     "key3" : "value3"
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a superfluous comma in the given input. The following assumes it has been removed.
2. The requested output is not valid JSON, so the following assumes the intent is for the output to be an array of objects (as shown below).  Other output formats are of course possible, including the one given in the original posting.
3. The following makes use of jq's "map" and "reduce" filters; please consult the jq documentation if you are unfamiliar with either of them.
4. For clarity, the following solution uses a helper function to combine an array of values with an array of key names:

   ```
   def convolve(headers):
     . as $in
     | reduce range(0; length) as $i ({}; . + {(headers[$i]): $in[$i]} );
   ```
5. With `convolve/1` as defined, we can now create the array of objects:

   ```
   .headers as $h | .rows | map( convolve($h) )
   ```
6. With the above jq program in a file (say program.jq), and the JSON in a file named input.json, the invocation:

   ```
   jq -f program.jq input.json
   ```

   produces:

   ```
   [
     {
       "key1": "value1",
       "key2": "value2",
       "key3": "value3"
     },
     {
       "key1": "value1",
       "key2": "value2",
       "key3": "value3"
     },
     {
       "key1": "value1",
       "key2": "value2",
       "key3": "value3"
     }
   ]
   ```
7. Here is a reduce-free definition of `convolve`; it assumes the availability of `transpose/0`, which is included with jq 1.5 and above:

   ```
   def convolve(headers):
     [., headers] | transpose | map( {(.[0]): .[1]} ) | add;
   ```
8. The following snippet is functionally equivalent to that shown in 5. above:

   ```
   .headers as $h
   | reduce .rows[] as $row ([]; . + [$row|convolve($h)])
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which uses a recursive function **obj** to build an object from arrays of keys and values.

```
def obj($keys; $values):
    if   $keys|length < 1
    then {} 
    else {($keys[0]): $values[0]} + obj($keys[1:]; $values[1:])
    end
;

[ obj(.headers; .rows[]) ]
```